# Checking if string is a palindrome returns wrong result

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to check if a string is a palindrome, using recursion. I am currently just trying to develop simple cases.

My function takes as input a string. It then strips away the punctuation. The next thing I do is check if the first letter of the word is equal to the last letter of the word. If it is then it returns string one. If it isn't then it returns a second string.

```
def palindrome(word):    
    stringOne = "It's a palindrome"
    stringTwo = "It's not a palindrome"
    edit = word.strip("!").strip(",").strip("")

    if edit[0] == edit[-1]:
        return stringOne 
    else:
        return stringTwo

print(palindrome("Yay!"))
```

The code is running. However, putting in the string "Yay!" (which is a palindrome) returns "It's not a palindrome." Any reason why my `if` statement isn't working?

Comment: First, you're only comparing the first character with the last. Second, you are comparing an uppercase letter to a lowercase error, i.e. "Y" versus "y". To check a palindrome properly, you would have to check each letter from the left to each letter from the right, and iterating over the following characters progressing in opposite directions.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the letter case issue that @RWRkeSBZ points out in the comments, this is a good example of where using a recursive *helper* function makes sense.  Once you clean up the string to contain only letters, there's no reason to do so again upon recursion.  Instead, we have a routine we call that deals with these issues and a more focused, recursive helper function that does the real processing:

```
def palindrome_recursive(letters):
    if len(letters) <= 1:
        return True

    if letters[0] != letters[-1]:
        return False

    return palindrome_recursive(letters[1:-1])

def palindrome(phrase):
    stringOne = "It's a palindrome"
    stringTwo = "It's not a palindrome"

    edit = phrase.strip("!,").strip().lower()

    if palindrome_recursive(edit):
        return stringOne

    return stringTwo

print(palindrome("Able was I ere I saw Elba!"))
```